# Cocos2d ARC link error for device but builds for the simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

Hi am following this tutorial to enable ARC for my cocos2d project

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/

The basic idea is to use cocos2d as a static library and disable the arc. It works on the simulator but crashes on my iPhone 5s

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCScaleTo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Helper.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCTexture2D", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_ccGLBlendFunc", referenced from:
      -[SlidingMenuGrid visit] in SlidingMenuGrid.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCLayer", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_SlidingMenuGrid in SlidingMenuGrid.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GameScene in GameScene.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_LevelScene in LevelScene.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Mask in Mask.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainScene in MainScene.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ResultScene in ResultScene.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PackScene in PackScene.o
      ...
  "_ccDrawPoints", referenced from:
      -[SlidingMenuGrid visit] in SlidingMenuGrid.o
  "_ccDrawPoint", referenced from:
      -[SlidingMenuGrid visit] in SlidingMenuGrid.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I use armv7 and armv7s for both the cocos2d library and the game target.

Comment: that's not a crash but a linker error. Probably related to build architectures not the same in both targets. Btw you should probably use v3 if this is for a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the latest version of Xcode where these options exist:

For both of your projects go into the Build Settings for each target and select "Standard Architectures (armv7, armv7s)" option in the Architectures field. Also have "Latest iOS (iOS 7.0)" selected for Base SDK. For the Valid Architectures field have at least "arm64, armv7, and armv7s".

This should fix your issue with the armv7 missing if you've had something different. Most likely your game/application project has something different if you initially created the project a while back with an older version of Xcode.